# position:fixed within an overflow:hidden parent - cross-browser alternative to background-attachment:fixed?

Tags: css, cross-browser, overflow, background-image, parallax

I have a fairly common use-case, a marketing page with a series of large images that I would like to *behave* like `background-attachment:fixed` but avoid the fairly significant performance problems with that approach.

By using a wrapper div, with `position:relative; z-index:0; overflow:hidden` around a full-screen fixed div containing the image, the effect is *exactly* what I want in Chrome and Safari (that I've tested so far):

http://codepen.io/geelen/pen/FxyKj

On Firefox, the `overflow:hidden` doesn't appear to have any effect, and so the three images on the page all render full-screen over the top of one another. Haven't had a chance to test IE at this point, but if I can get at least Chrome & Firefox working & performing nicely, that'll be a start.

Interestingly, dropping the `z-index:0` breaks the effect on Chrome as well, as `position:relative` with an auto z-index doesn't introduce a new stacking context, which appears to be what's causing the `overflow:hidden` to have an effect. I'm wondering if there's a way to get Firefox to render in a similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

How about using this code? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vFJxk

```
.image {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  background-size: cover;
  //position: fixed;
  //top: 0;
  //left: 0;
  //z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
```

I've double-checked in IE 11, it's working perfectly.

Comment: That might work, but it performs horribly (all `background-attachment:fixed` does, except on Chrome Canary which has an optimisation). The question is about a high-performing alternative to `background-attachment:fixed`.